# How to troubleshoot bluetooth audio for a Surface tablet?

Tags: windows-10, audio, video, bluetooth, microsoft-surface-3

From bluetooth settings (`start ms-settings:bluetooth`) clicking `disconnect` and `connect` generates an audible pairing message from the headset.

Hower, youtube or other video only seems to play over the built-in audio.

One time `zoom` worked.

The `PLT v5200` from plantronics works with other devices.

Not sure what I can do.  I removed the device and re-added it.

---

I removed the device from bluetooth.

Added an Alexa speaker.  YouTube plays fine over the Alexa speaker.

Disconnected from the Alexa speaker.

Connected to the 5200 earpiece.
Audio still plays over the built-in speakers.

In bluetooth settings, it now shows as:

`Connected voice`

which is probably the problem.

Comment: Have you left clicked the speaker icon in the bottom left of the taskbar and chosen the output device you want to use? If you left-click the speaker icon you will get a volume slider and the name of the current playback (output) device. You can click that name to select a different device.

Comment: I think that's pretty much the answer @Mokubai so thx